# Equation of plane without cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, matrices, vector-spaces

We know that vectors $(3,3,4)$ and $(-1,-1,5)$ span a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Can we somehow readily infer that the plane's equation is $x_1 - x_2 = 0$? Cross-products have not yet been introduced and are therefore out of the question. I was hoping it would be possible by means of row reduction; I attempted to row reduce

$\left[  \begin{array}{cc|c} 3 & -1 & x \\ 3 & -1 & y \\ 4 & 5 & z \end{array}  \right] \ ,$

but that only reduces to the identity matrix, so no luck there. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the origin included?

Comment: According to the picture in my book, yes. But on that note: Why wouldn't it? $x_1 = x_2 = 0$ gives us the origin anyway.

Comment: Your original approach works fine; if you row reduce $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -1 & x\\3 & -1 & y\\4 & 5 & z\end{pmatrix}$, you will get a matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & *\\ 0 & 1 & *\\ 0 & 0 & y-x\end{pmatrix}$ where * indicates an expression in x and z; so the system is consistent iff $x=y$.

Comment: @user84413: Fantastic, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a plane is $ax + by + cz = d$.  Since $(0,0,0)$ lies in the plane we see that $d = 0$; our equation becomes $ax + by + cz = 0$.

The point $(3,3,4)$ lies on the plane so $3a + 3b + 4c = 0$.  The point $(-1,-1,5)$ lies on the plane so we have $-a -b + 5c = 0$.

Solve the equations; the solution is a one-parameter family.  Any $(a,b,c)$ you obtain will work, save for the zero solution.

Comment: So we're essentially solving
$ \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 3 & 4 \\-1 & -1 & 5  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = \textbf{0}$, right? I guess you could pop out a general form of the plane equation and plug-and-chug given points. Seemingly there is no "row-reduction"-approach out of which the plane equation can be read off.

Comment: Row reduction yields $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = \textbf{0}$  You can see that $x = -y$ and $z=0$ gives you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The plane is the set of vectors that are coplanar with the given two. But three vectors are coplanar if the matrix having these vectors as rows has zero determinant. So the equation of the plane is
$$
\left| 
\matrix
{x & y & z \\
3 & 3 & 4 \\
-1 & -1 & 5}
\right| =0
$$